# What does the <E> syntax mean in Java?

Tags: java, syntax

I've quickly googled for an answer but could not not find/think of accurate search parameters.

I am teaching myself Java, but can't seem to find the meaning of a certain syntax.

```
public class Node<E>{
    E elem;
    Node<E> next, previous;
}
```

What does the `<E>` signify?  I vaguely remember the arrow braces having something to do with vectors but based on the code above I get the feeling it has to do with enumerations.

Any assistance or clarification would be greatly appreciated.  Thank you.

Comment: Google for "generics"

Comment: The title of your question gives little indication what it is about.  Please consider renaming it, e.g. "What does the <E> syntax mean in Java?"

Comment: You are correct, how would I go about changing the title?  I do not readily see the option to do so.

Comment: think the title's fine, "syntax" adds little. if you wanted to change, perhaps "what does the <E> in Node<E> mean in Java". @d.lanza38 click `edit` (under the tags, between `share` and `flag`)

Answer (score 63, accepted):

These are called [Generics](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/index.html).

In general, these enable *types* (classes and interfaces) to be parameters when defining classes, interfaces and methods.

Using generics give many benefits over using non-generic code, as shown the following from Java's tutorial:

- **Stronger type checks at compile time.** A Java compiler applies strong type checking to generic code and issues errors if the code violates type safety. Fixing compile-time errors is easier than fixing runtime errors, which can be difficult to find.

  For example:

  ```
  // without Generics
  List list = new ArrayList();
  list.add("hello");

  // With Generics
  List<Integer> list = new ArrayList<Integer>();
  list.add("hello"); // will not compile
  ```
- **Enabling programmers to implement generic algorithms.** By using generics, programmers can implement generic algorithms that work on collections of different types, can be customized, and are type safe and easier to read.
- **Elimination of casts.**

  For example, the following code snippet without generics requires casting:

  ```
  List list = new ArrayList();
  list.add("hello");
  String s = (String) list.get(0);
  ```

  When re-written to use generics, the code does not require casting:

  ```
  List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
  list.add("hello");
  String s = list.get(0); // no cast
  ```

Answer (score 28):

Here `<E>` denotes the type parameter of **Node** class .The type parameter defines that it can refer to any type (like String, Integer, Employee etc.). Java generics have type parameter naming conventions like following:

1. T - Type
2. E - Element
3. K - Key
4. N - Number
5. V - Value

For example take the following scenerio

```
public class Node<E>{
   E elem;
   Node<E> next, previous;
}
class Test{
   Node<String> obj = new Node<>();
}
```

For the above scenerio, in background the **Node** class 'E' will reference the **String** type and class will be look like following

```
public class Node<String>{
   String elem;
   Node<String> next,previous;
}
```

Not only String you can also use Integer,Character,Employee etc as a type parameter.

You can use generics with Interface,method and constructor too.

For more about generics visit these:

https://www.journaldev.com/1663/java-generics-example-method-class-interface
https://www.javatpoint.com/generics-in-java

Answer (score 1):

The  is the java syntax way of indicating a Generic Type. Essentially this just means that it can be a Node object that can take on any type at all.

you should check [this](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/) out for a good turorial on java generics

Comment: The wording is ambiguous- what does "take on" mean?